# Search all branches for a string but limit commits to a specific author?

Tags: git

I can use this to search all branches for a certain string.

```
git grep "something" $(git rev-list --all)
```

How can I do the same thing but limit to commits by a specific author?

Comment: **limit commits to a specific author?** you mean whether that user has added that string into the code? or is it if the author is part of that commit or working on the same repository (this makes no sense). I feel the question is little ambiguous.

Comment: Yes I mean if that user has added that string into the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use git log for this with the --all tag and --author to search all branches and a particular author:

```
git log --all --author=name_of_author
```

There are many other filters you can add to git log to help narrow down your search criteria. Here is the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

And then you can pipe your grep after your git log to filter what you want

```
git log --all --author=name_of_author | grep 'stuff'
```